# Is there any markdown or standard way to handle placeholders in strings to be parsed later by the front end?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to store something in the database that would then be retrieved and parsed by the client.

The item stores an action of a user by its user's id.

Something like " #userId has done something".

Since I'm using a NoSQL database, the username of the user can change so I can't just store it inside the string. So I have to store the user id inside the string. The client should then parse the string, realize that they are seeing a userid, fetch from the server and replace it with the result. Is there any standard way of doing something like this?

Comment: I wouldn't use a database to hold template data. Sounds like you'd be better off having something like a `usersThatHaveDoneSomething` array and pipe that through a template later. But it's kind of a vague question without a lot of specifics so that's all I can give you back.

Comment: you're looking for a templating language like handlebars, mustache, or a ton of others

Comment: @mccambridge Hey, thanks for the answer. Yeah it's more of an event. Pretty much there are 5 or 6 events . It's basically inside a chat. When a user is kicked, joined chat, etc.

Comment: @imjared is correct. But since it seems you are using sockets we need to know what you are using on the frontend for your JS lib. React? Angular? jQuery? Something else?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin react native. I am using sockets but I also want those events to persist in a chatroom msg history

Comment: I was thinking something like

[["user", id], ["message", "has invited", ["user", id]]

And the entire array can be joined by a space once each individual item is parsed and resolved. But Im wondering if there is a better way

Comment: You just have to set state in the component method that is handling the response from the event. Then use `{this.state.whatever}` in the template to get the new value.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin But how would the front-end know where to fetch the resource?

If I'm storing a user's uuid in a string, I want it to be able to know that and replace it with a user's name or something

Comment: How do you get the `uuid`? From a database? The user's name should be stored with that data. Bring it all down together.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Right, but when I'm storing something like {{user#uuid}} has joined

Does handlebars allow me to recognize that a user's id is following the #?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I'm just a little confused because I've always used handlebars to handle dynamic data in html

Comment: Please post your component's code above so I can help you. Right now I'm just guessing

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how and where you want to display those actions and what are your other requirements. What data are available for processing on page (userId,url etc).

As you are using NoSQL database there can be many such scenarios. You can use templating engines like [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/), [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) or others (there are quite a few) to display and process fetched data from the database.

Again, it all depends on what technology you are using. There is not much information to go further. Please share more information about the environment.

Comment: I'm using Cassandra and Nodejs for the back-end, react-native for the front-end.

Basically when I load a chatroom I fetch from the Message table. Basically I want to reuse these chatroom events inside the message table so that it would always return whenever we load a chatroom.

So I need to store something like {user@UUID} has done something 

as the body of my message, and then have the front end recognize that it is a UUID, fetch the resource through my api and swap the username in the string instead of the UUID.